# Regex to add square brackets into beginning/end sentence and also each word separate by comma?

Tags: java, regex

What kind of regex do I need to use to add square brackets into beginning/end sentence and also each word separate by comma?

I have a sentence like this:

```
qqqqqqq\
asadsds\
dsdadad\
sadadad\
asdsada\
dsadadd";
```

I expecting to get result like this:

```
[qqqqqq, asadsds, dsdadad, sadadad, asdsada, dsadadd]
```

I try many things such as:

```
String regex1 = "(^[a-zA-z_0-9])(\\s)([a-zA-z_0-9]$)";
```

Comment: Is the result a `String` or a `String[]` / `List<String>`? Try `text.split("\\p{L}+")`

Comment: I meant, `text.split("\\P{L}+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to split the input string into some "words" thus excluding all non-letter or non-word characters as delimiters using `String.split("\\W+")` or `String.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")`.

Then re-join the cleaned words using commas and adding brackets which can be provided by `Arrays.toString` method.

This can be implemented simply:

```java
String input = "qqqqqqq\\\nasadsds\\\ndsdadad\\\nsadadad\\\nasdsada\\\ndsadadd\";";
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println("------------");
String result = Arrays.toString(input.split("\\W+"));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
qqqqqqq\
asadsds\
dsdadad\
sadadad\
asdsada\
dsadadd";
------------
[qqqqqqq, asadsds, dsdadad, sadadad, asdsada, dsadadd]
```